# Parse an array in php posted by an html form

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, forms

I have the following problem.
I have these types of select inside my form:

```
<select name="variation[8][]" multiple>
   <option value="1">s</option>
   <option value="2">m</option>
   <option value="3">l</option>
</select>

<select name="variation[9][]" multiple>
   <option value="8">red</option>
   <option value="9">blue</option>
   <option value="10">black</option>
</select>
```

I want to read the posted array properly with php and I want to write this in the database:

```
variation_id => 8 
variation_term => 1 
variation_id => 8 
variation_term => 2 
variation_id => 8 
variation_term => 3 

variation_id => 9 
variation_term => 8 
variation_id => 9 
variation_term => 9 
variation_id => 9 
variation_term => 10
```

How can I parse this array posted?
There is a better way to do this?

TNX

I have found this solution:

```
foreach ($_POST['variation'] as $key => $value) {
   for($i=0; $i<count($value); $i++){
     echo "varitaion name = $key"."<br>";
     echo "value = $value[$i]";
   }
}
```

Comment: DO you want to fetch the values from POST array?

Comment: yes but no a simple post array name="variable[]" but from name="variable[8][]" because I need to know VALUES of that select and the select variable[NAME]. So in my database I will write the name of the variant => 8 Example. variant=>8 value=>1 variant=>8 value=>2 and if i have another SELECT variant=>9 value=>10 variant =>8 value=>15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
foreach($_POST['variation'] as $key=>$val){
  if(is_array($val)){
     echo " Values for $key Are:"; // get your variation index eg:8,9 etc
     foreach($val as $key1=>$val1){
         echo $val1.","; // get the index values
     }
         echo "<br/>";
  }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! I made a similar solution I have edited my question! 
thanks so much!